# An Exocortex tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I understand that there probably isn't much of an exocortex community, I've only just discovered it, but I [recently had a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454814/exocortex-seems-to-interfere-with-mediaelement) that was almost entirely about [exocortex](http://www.exocortex.com/) and could not tag it as such. Any chance that tag could be added by someone old and wiser than me?

Comment: Links to the question and to exocortex please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag created, tag wiki started, question tagged. Go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/exocortex/info) and edit the tag wiki into something decent, and you can get a few rep points when it's approved.